# JSON data formatting in Python

Tags: python, json, oracle, python-2.7

I am retrieving multiple columns from a database table. One of the column names is the value that contains JSON data. If I select the only value column from the database, then I get a record in following format.

```
value = (u'{"time":["9599","MS"],"What is your birth place?":["USA"]}',)
```

However, if I select value column with other columns then I get record in following format:

```
value = {"time":["9599","MS"],"What is your birth place?":["USA"]}
```

I need value in the first format because I want to separate the key and value pair from the data with the following code.

```
dict = json.loads(value[0])
dict.keys()
dict.values()
```

My output should look like following.

```
Keys
-----
time 
What is your birth place?

Value:
------
9599 
MS
USA
```

How to convert data from second format to first format?

Comment: For the second format, don't `value.keys()` and `value.values()` accomplish what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call `str()` on `value` and then  create the required tuple:

```
value = {"time":["9599","MS"],"What is your birth place?":["USA"]}
value = (str(value),)
print value
>> ("{'What is your birth place?': ['USA'], 'time': ['9599', 'MS']}", )
```

**EDIT:** Actually it will be better to use `json.dumps()` which takes a Python dictionary and returns a `json` string:

```
value = {'time':['9599','MS'],'What is your birth place?':['USA']}

import json

value = (json.dumps(value),)
print value
>> ('{"What is your birth place?": ["USA"], "time": ["9599", "MS"]}', )
```